# How to count number of unique values in pandas while each cell includes list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

```
Out[10]: 
       samples  subject  trial_num
0    [0 2 2        1          1
1    [3 3 0        1          2
2    [1 1 1        1          3
3    [0 1 2        2          1
4    [4 5 6        2          2
5    [0 8 8        2          3
```

I want to have the output like this:

```
       samples  subject  trial_num   frequency
0    [0 2 2        1          1      2    
1    [3 3 0        1          2      2
2    [1 1 1        1          3      1
3    [0 1 2        2          1      3
4    [4 5 6        2          2      3
5    [0 8 8        2          3      2
```

The frequency here is the number of unique values in each list per sample. For example, `[0, 2, 2]` only have one unique value.

I can do the unique values in pandas without having a list, or implement it using for loop to go through each row access each list and .... but I want a better pandas way to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Why is `[0, 2, 2]` only one unique value and not two: `[0,2]` are not the same

Comment: Point of clarification: `[0, 2, 2]` has _2_ unique values, `0` and `2`. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: @It_is_Chris you are right just correct it

Comment: @G.Anderson my bad I just correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `collections.Counter` for the task:

```
from collections import Counter

df['frequency'] = df['samples'].apply(lambda x: sum(v==1 for v in Counter(x).values()))

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     samples  subject  trial_num  frequency
0  [0, 2, 2]        1          1          1
1  [3, 3, 0]        1          2          1
2  [1, 1, 1]        1          3          0
3  [0, 1, 2]        2          1          3
4  [4, 5, 6]        2          2          3
5  [0, 8, 8]        2          3          1
```

---

EDIT: For updated question:

```
df['frequency'] = df['samples'].apply(lambda x: len(set(x)))

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     samples  subject  trial_num  frequency
0  [0, 2, 2]        1          1          2
1  [3, 3, 0]        1          2          2
2  [1, 1, 1]        1          3          1
3  [0, 1, 2]        2          1          3
4  [4, 5, 6]        2          2          3
5  [0, 8, 8]        2          3          2
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Actually, I just updated my question as to the list I have in each cell does not have `,` and it seems, in this case, it is counting incorrectly

Comment: @sariii so type of values of `sample` column is `string` and not `list`?

Comment: Give me one moment please to double-check.

Comment: So sorry for the confusion, pandas says its an object. Again I updated the true looks of the item. The thing is that I have many data on that. That's why I never check the end of the list.  Its like this: `[1 2 3    without even having end of `]`

Comment: @sariii The best approach here is to clean your data before creating the dataframe. Seems you have strings in your column, so convert these strings to lists fist.

Comment: Instead of updating the original question, mistakenly I was updating your answer :))), sorry for that. so you mean its better to convert each of these to list and then call your code?

Comment: @sariii Yes, I mean exactly that. When the type of `samples` column is `list`, run my code and you should have the desired result.

Comment: I remove`[` from the entire column. Now I kind of face with the original question. I tried this to convert the numbers to list `df['samples'].apply(lambda x: list(x))`. However, it behaves `168` as three items. seems it removes the spaces and convert all individual number to one item in the list but its not what I want (I have bigger numbers in that list like: 168  178  190  0  9  )

Comment: @sariii Try `x.split()` this will make a list e.g. `['1', '2', '3']`

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import ast # import for sample data creation
from io import StringIO # import for sample data creation

# sample data
s = """samples;subject;trial_num
[0, 2, 2];1;1
[3, 3, 0];1;2
[1, 1, 1];1;3
[0, 1, 2];2;1
[4, 5, 6];2;2
[0, 8, 8];2;3"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), sep=';')
df['samples'] = df['samples'].apply(ast.literal_eval)

# convert lists to a new frame and use nunique
# assign values to a col
df['frequency'] = pd.DataFrame(df['samples'].values.tolist()).nunique(1)


     samples  subject  trial_num  frequency
0  [0, 2, 2]        1          1          2
1  [3, 3, 0]        1          2          2
2  [1, 1, 1]        1          3          1
3  [0, 1, 2]        2          1          3
4  [4, 5, 6]        2          2          3
5  [0, 8, 8]        2          3          2
```